# onMounted hook is not called by Vue

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have two components, one is managing data, the other is a vue template. I have simplified them here. The problem is that when the locations come in via the fetch, the `locations` in the vue template stays empty. I've checked with `isRef()` and that returns true, but it's just an empty array. Looking in the Vue dev tools panel, the `locations` *does* have elements in the array.

**Locations.js**

```js
import {
    ref,
    isRef,
    onMounted,
} from 'vue';


export default function useLocations () {
    const locations = ref([]);

    const loadImageData = (locId) => {
        
        isRef(locations); // === true
        
        // @FIXME locations.value is always empty here.
        locations.value.forEach( (loc,key) => {
            console.debug( loc.id, locId )
        })
    };

    const getLocations = async () => {
        const locs = await apiFetch({ path: '/wp/v2/tour-location'});
        locations.value = locs;
    };

    onMounted( getLocations );

    return {
        locations,
        getLocations,
        loadImageData,
    };
}
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="location">
        <h1>{{ location.name }}</h1>
        <img :src="location.main_image" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import useLocations from '@/composables/Locations';

export default {
    name: 'Location',
    props: [,'location'],
    data () {return {}},
    watch: {
        location: {
            // deep: true,
            immediate: true,
            handler: function(){
                const { loadImageData } = useLocations();
                loadImageData( location.id );
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

When `loadImageData()` is called from the `Location.vue` component, `locations` is always an empty array. Why doesn't it get updated in *that* function as it does in other places within the app?

Answer (score 5):

`onMounted` is a hook registration function.

> These lifecycle hook registration functions can only be used **synchronously during** `setup()`, since they rely on internal global state to locate the current active instance (the component instance whose `setup()` is being called right now). Calling them without a current active instance will result in an error.

[*emphasis mine*]

[Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks)

As you are using your `useLocations` composition function outside `setup()`, your `getLocations` function is never called and `locations` is always empty array

To explain it further. You do not **have** to call `onMounted` (or any other hook registration function) **directly inside** `setup()`. It is perfectly fine to place that call into separate composition function outside any component (as you did) **but** that function must then be used from inside the `setup()`

Comment: Thank you, `loadImageData` is actually in the returned object, I forgot it in example, fixed now. I'll have to look into `onMounted` further, because I thought the whole point was to be able to use it _outside_ of a component.

Comment: Actually, yeah, look at this example: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#standalone-computed-properties -- `onMounted` is called inside the extracted `useUserRepositories` function, even though there is no `setup()` function.

Comment: Nope, all lifecycle registration functions **must** be used inside `setup()` of component. Otherwise how would Vue know to which component it should be attached ?

Comment: To example: Yes, it is fine **but** then the `useUserRepositories` function is called from `setup()`